# Why doesn't el.scrollIntoView() scroll to the specified element?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

There is a list of posts that is generated as follows:

```
async function getPosts() {
  let res = await fetch('./api/posts');
  let posts = await res.json();

  const postList = document.querySelector('.post-list');
  postList.innerHTML = '';

  posts.forEach((post) => {
    postList.innerHTML += `

      <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 bg-light">
        <div class="card-body ">
          <h5 class="card-title">${post.title}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">${post.body}</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Подробнее...</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link" onclick="removePost(${post.id})">Remove</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link" onclick="selectPost('${post.id}', '${post.title}', '${post.body}')">Update</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    `
  });
}

getPosts();
```

Here is the selectPost() function:

```
function selectPost(id, title, body) {
  window.idToUpdate = id;
  document.getElementById('title-edit').value = title;
  document.getElementById('body-edit').value = body;
  document.getElementById('update-form').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  console.log(document.getElementById('update-form'));        // <div id="update-form" class="row col-lg-4 col-sm-16 my-3">
}
```

The form has the `update-form` id:

```
<div class="row col-lg-4 col-sm-16 my-3" id="update-form">
        <h2>Update post</h2>
...
```

When clicking on the "Update" link, scrolling occurs to the top of the document, and not to the form with the id `update-form`, although when calling the selectPost() function, the form element is displayed in the console:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('update-form'));        // <div id="update-form" class="row col-lg-4 col-sm-16 my-3">
```

How can I fix the bug? Thanks a lot in advance.

I think I did write, but frustrated that it doesn't work.

Comment: Your template doesn't have an id? And if it gets assigned somewhere else, your potentially getting multiple posts so there would be duplicate id?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you want this

```
document.querySelector('.post-list div.card:last-child')
  .scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
```

Also you need to stop the default behaviour of the link which is to reload the page when your href is `#` - I do that with `e.preventDefault();` in the following code:

I have added an eventListener too so you do not need the inline event handlers

```js
const posts = [
{"id":"id1","title":"title 1", "body":"Body 1"},
{"id":"id2","title":"title 2", "body":"Body 2"},
{"id":"id3","title":"title 3", "body":"Body 3"},
{"id":"id4","title":"title 4", "body":"Body 4"},
{"id":"id5","title":"title 5", "body":"Body 5"}
];
const postList = document.querySelector('.post-list');
postList.innerHTML = posts.map(post => `
      <div class="card col-lg-4 col-sm-6 bg-light" data-id="${post.id}">
        <div class="card-body ">
          <h5 class="card-title">${post.title}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">${post.body}</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Подробнее...</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link remove">Remove</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link update">Update</a>
        </div>
      </div>`)
  .join("");

document.querySelector('.post-list div.card:last-child').scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"}); 

const selectPost = (id, title, body) => {
  console.log(id, title, body);
};

postList.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".card-link");
  if (!tgt) return; // not a link
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
  const card = tgt.closest("div.card");
  if (tgt.matches(".remove")) card.remove();
  else if (tgt.matches(".update")) {
    selectPost(card.dataset.id, card.querySelector(".card-title").textContent.trim(),
      card.querySelector(".card-text").textContent.trim());
  }
})
```

```css
.card {
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<div class="post-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of your click on the `<a>` element, which, since it has a `href="#"` attribute, is to scroll to the top of the page, overriding your own call to `scrollIntoView()`:

```js
addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.dataset.prevent === "true") {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  document.querySelector(".target").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
});
```

```css
.target { margin-top: 300vh }
```

```html
<a href="#" data-prevent="false">do not prevent default</a>
<a href="#" data-prevent="true">prevent default</a>
<div class="target">scrolled to me</div>
```

---

*Ps: note that in the StackSnippet the whole call to `scrollIntoView()` isn't overridden. Indeed, we are in an `<iframe>`, and `scrollIntoView()` does work across nested viewports. The scroll initiated by `<a>`'s navigation stays inside the `<iframe>` document, so it only prevents the scrolling inside the `<iframe>`.*

Comment: Right, man. The fact is that addEventListener will not work if we put it in outside the `getPosts()` function cause the card templates will not be loaded in the `DOM` yet. So we have to put the event initialisation into `forEach` method inside the `getPosts() `function.

Comment: In your `selectPost` function add `event.preventDefault();` somewhere.

Comment: So how can I pass the event from `onclick` attribute? Like this? So how can I pass the event from onclick attribute? Like this?
`onclick="selectPost(this.event)"`

Comment: You don't really need to, `event` is a global property and corresponds to the currently active Event. That's ugly, but so are `onevent` attributes. If you can the best would be to use event delegation, but we're going a bit far from the original cause of your issue.

Comment: Sorry, now I have anchor links in my cards but when I use e.preventDefault(), I lose the card anchor link in the URL. How can I keep it?

Answer (score -1):

I’m unable to run/test your bits and pieces of code but…
*scrollIntoView* works when applied to the parent of the element you want to scroll, like this example:

```
e.parentElement.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
```

NB: "e" being the element you want to scroll.

Comment: No, man. Unfortunately that doesn't work for my layout. Al the cards have only one parent element, but I need to scroll exactly to the card  that user clicked on it.